# Pages appear to be loading twice

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

When running ASPNetBoilerplate in debug mode, if I have a breakpoint in my controllers, when I access the site from the url, the breakpoint is accessed twice. is there something I might have changed that would cause this.

(breakpoint on HomeController/Index even fires twice).

Comment: Create a repro on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with different browser. some browsers resend the request if it fails. so when you wait on the debug line it might be trying to resend the request.

another option; clear breakpoints and write a log to see the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was the browser doing it.